# Optimization of basic image processing in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, optimization

I'm trying to accomplish a basic image processing. Here is my algorithm :

Find n., n+1., n+2. pixel's RGB values in a row and create a new image from these values.

[image: Algorithm]

Here is my example code in python :

```
import glob
import ntpath
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

images = glob.glob('model/*.png')
pool_size = 17


def worker(image_file):
    try:
        new_image = np.zeros((2400, 1280, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        image_name = ntpath.basename(image_file)
        print(f'Processing [{image_name}]')

        image = Image.open(image_file)
        data = np.asarray(image)

        for i in range(0, 2399):
            for j in range(0, 1279):
                pix_x = j * 3 + 1
                red = data[i, pix_x - 1][0]
                green = data[i, pix_x][1]
                blue = data[i, pix_x + 1][2]
                new_image[i, j] = [red, green, blue]

        im = Image.fromarray(new_image)
        im.save(f'export/{image_name}')
    except:
        print('error with item')


pool = Pool(pool_size)
for image_file in images:
    pool.apply_async(worker, (image_file,))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

My input and output images are in RGB format. My code is taking 5 second for every image. I'm open for any idea to optimization this task.

Here is example input and output images :

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84jvb.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84jvb.png) [ 3840 x 2400 ]

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGn4L.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGn4L.png) [ 1280 x 2400 ]

Comment: Include the pic in the question, not as link.

Comment: This is well answered by @Lukáš-Lalinský [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581014/how-can-i-process-images-faster-with-python#:~:text=Generally%2C%20you%20want%20to%20avoid,a%20combination%20of%20the%20two.Generally, you want to avoid per-pixel loops in Python. They will always be slow. To get somewhat fast image processing, you need to get used to working with matrices instead of individual pixels. You have basically two options, you can either use NumPy or OpenCV, or a combination of the two...

Comment: So your output image is 1/3 width and 1/3 the height of your input image? Please show input and output images.

Comment: added example input and output images

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load input image
im = cv2.imread('input.png')

# Calculate new first layer - it is every 3rd pixel of the first layer of im
n1 = im[:, ::3, 0]

# Calculate new second layer - it is every 3rd pixel of the second layer of im, starting with an offset of 1 pixel
n2 = im[:, 1::3, 1]

# Calculate new third layer - it is every 3rd pixel of the third layer of im, starting with an offset of 2 pixels
n3 = im[:, 2::3, 2]

# Now stack the three new layers to make a new output image
res = np.dstack((n1,n2,n3))
```

Comment: dstack is compression on both axis. is it possible to compress only one axis ?

Comment: `hstack` appends images side-by-side horizontally. `vstack` appends images one above the other vertically. `dstack` stacks images by channels, or depthwise. No compression involved. It is the same as `np.stack(..., axis=2, ...)`

Comment: By the way, if you are happier writing loops, you could look at `numba`, example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55356126/2836621

Comment: By the way, threads don't buy you much with Python as, apart from I/O, only one thread will be active at a time because of the GIL. You may therefore want multiprocessing rather than multithreading. Try watching your CPUs with `htop` or **Process Monitor** while processing to see if all cores are 100% busy.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from the question, you want to shift the pixel values of each channel of the input image in the output image. So, here is my approach.

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('my_image.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im = np.pad(im, [(3, 3),(3,3),(0,0)], mode='constant', constant_values=0) # Add padding for enabling the shifting process later

r= im[:,:,0]

g= im[:,:,1]
g = np.delete(g,np.s_[-1],axis=1) # remove the last column
temp_pad = np.zeros(shape=(g.shape[0],1)) # removed part
g = np.concatenate((temp_pad,g),axis=1) # put the removed part back


b = im[:,:,2]
b = np.delete(b,np.s_[-2::],axis=1) # remove the last columns
temp_pad = np.zeros(shape=(b.shape[0],2)) # removed parts
b = np.concatenate((temp_pad,b),axis=1) # put the removed parts back


new_im = np.dstack((r,g,b)) # Merge the channels
new_im = new_im[3:-3,3:-3,:]/np.amax(new_im)#*255 # Remove the padding
```

Basically, I achieved the shifting by padding&merging the green and blue channels. Let me know if this is what you are looking for. Kolay gelsin :)